# Why component to not re-render when props change?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have problem that render method doesnt run when the props value is changed. What am I doing wrong? I tried using componentwillrecieveprops but it also doesnt run.

ChildComponent:

```
 state = {
    data: this.props.populatedWords,
    allSelected: false,
    res: null,
    textAreaVal: null,
    editMode: new Array(this.props.populatedWords.length).fill(false),
    entityList: [],
    selectedEntity: [],
    parts: [],
    final: null,
    entityObject: null,
    sendToUpdateEntity: null,
    arr: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('intents'))[localStorage.getItem('intent')],
    selectedValue: null,
    textInput: "",
    token: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).tokens.training
};



componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("i am called")
    // You don't have to do this check first, but it can help prevent an unneeded render
    if (nextProps.words !== this.state.data) {
        this.setState({ data: nextProps.words });
    }
}

render() {

    return (
        <Card className={classes.root} style={{maxWidth: '100%'}}>
            <NoRazmetkaDialog ref={this.dialog}/>
            <NoEntityDialog ref={this.dialogE}/>
            <HalfRazmetkaDialog ref={this.dialogHalf}/>
            <CardHeader action={<Grid container>
                <Grid item style={{display: 'flex'}}>
                    <Tooltip>
                        <FilterOptions updateSelected={this.updateSelectedValue}/>
                    </Tooltip>
                    <TextField variant="standard" style={{paddingTop: '10px'}} onChange={e => {
                        this.setState({textInput: e.target.value});
                    }}/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>}/>
            <div className={classes.tableWrapper}>
                <Table className={classes.table} aria-labelledby="tableTitle">
                    <IntentTableHead data={this.state.data} updateAllSelected={this.updateAllSelected}
                                     allSelected={this.state.allSelected} updateData={this.updateData}
                                     sendToDialogflow={this.sendToDialogFlow} updateEntity={this.updateEntity}
                                     entityObject={this.state.entityObject}/>
                    <TableBody>
                        {this.state.data.map((val, i) => {
                            return (
                                <TableRow hover>
                                    <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                                        <Checkbox checked={this.state.data[i].checked}
                                                  onChange={this.addCheckedPhrase(i)}/>
                                    </TableCell>
                                    {!this.state.editMode[i] &&
                                    <TableCell onClick={this.changeEditMode(i)}>
                                        {val.word}
                                    </TableCell>}
                                    {this.state.editMode[i] &&
                                    <TableCell>
                                        <TextField
                                            multiline
                                            defaultValue={val.word}
                                            className={classes.textField}
                                            margin="none"
                                            variant="outlined"
                                            value={this.state.textAreaVal}
                                            onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, i, 'word')}
                                        />
                                        <Button onClick={this.changeEditMode(i)}>OK</Button>
                                    </TableCell>
                                    }
                                    <TableCell>
                                        {array[localStorage.getItem('intent')].display_name}
                                    </TableCell>
                                    {this.state.data[i].test === null &&
                                    <TableCell>
                                        Тестировать
                                    </TableCell>}
                                    {this.state.data[i].test !== null &&
                                    <TableCell>
                                        {this.state.data[i].test}
                                    </TableCell>}
                                    <TableCell>
                                        <Select value={this.state.data[i].entity}
                                                onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, i, 'entity')}
                                                inputProps={{name: "data"}}>
                                            {this.state.entityList.map((val, i) => {
                                                return (<MenuItem value={val} key={i}>{val}</MenuItem>)
                                            })}
                                        </Select>
                                    </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>
                                        <Button onClick={this.updateIntent(i)}>Обучить</Button>
                                    </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>
                                        <IconButton onClick={this.deleteRow(i)}>
                                            <ClearIcon/>
                                        </IconButton>
                                    </TableCell>
                                </TableRow>
                            );
                        })}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </div>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

Parent component:

```
 render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <PositionedDialog ref={this.dialog} selectedWord={this.state.selectedWord} textAreaVal={this.state.textAreaVal} updateRes={this.updateRes}/>
            <IconButton variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        component={Link} to="/app/intent"
                        onClick={this.backToComponent}
            >
                <KeyboardArrowLeft/>
            </IconButton>
            <Paper>
                <Toolbar>
                    <Grid container alignItems="center">
                        <Grid item xs alignItems="center">
                            <TextField
                                fullWidth
                                onFocus
                                id="help"
                                InputProps={{
                                    disableUnderline: true
                                }}
                                value={this.state.textAreaVal}
                                onKeyPress={e => {
                                    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                                        this.findSelectedText();
                                    }
                                }}
                                onChange={e => {
                                    this.setState({textAreaVal: e.target.value});
                                }}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Toolbar>
            </Paper>
            <Paper style={{marginTop: "20px", overflow: "hidden"}}>
                {this.state.generator > 0 && this.state.populatedWords !== null &&
                <IntentTable populatedWords={this.state.populatedWords}/>}
            </Paper>
        </div>
    );
}
```

this.state.data form a table. and when my this.props.words is updated it does not add row to the table. I see that the problem is with it.

Answer (score 1):

`this.state.data` is not being used in your render method

Comment: sorry, I accidently put other component here, please see edited verison

Comment: Did you use lifecycle method `ComponentWillUpdate()` to verify if re-render is made?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should be using [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) as componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated.
To address your issue, regarding your componentWillReceiveProps, it appears you're comparing `this.state.data` of your child with `nextProps.words`, yet it appears to me you're sending : `<IntentTable populatedWords={this.state.populatedWords}/>` so your prop name is `populateWords`. Try changing this and keep me updated!

Answer (score 0):

to avoid using lifecycle methods, don't save your props to state in your child component. Remove `data` and `editMode` from state.

In your child render access the props directly

```
render() {
 const data = this.props.populatedWords;
 const editMode = new Array(this.props.populatedWords.length).fill(false);
 ...
}
```